# I want to increment the month but my code does not give me a satisfactory result

Tags: php

I have a date that is initialized. I want to increment the month but my code does not give me a satisfactory result.

this is what i would like to get

```
2022-10-31
2022-11-30
2022-12-31
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
```

this is my code

```
$debut_paie = '2022-10-31';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) :
 
$date = new DateTime($debut_paie);
$date -> modify('+'.$i.' month');
$debut_paye = $date -> format('Y-m-d');

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO echeance_details VALUES('','".$id_cl."','$debut_paie','$debut_paye','".$montant_par_mois."',0)";
$insert = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
$insert->execute();
endfor;
```

here is what i get get

```
2022-10-31
2022-12-01
2022-12-31
2023-01-31
2023-03-03
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the initial date object out of the loop (this will interfere and reset the date on each loop), change your date modification to a relative string at the end of the loop, and change the loop operator to ensure you only have 5 entries.

```php
$debut_paie = '2022-10-31';
$date = new DateTime($debut_paie); // Moved out of loop

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) : // Changed to < to keep only 5 date iterations
    $debut_paye = $date -> format('Y-m-d');

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO echeance_details VALUES('','".$id_cl."','$debut_paie','$debut_paye','".$montant_par_mois."',0)";
    $insert = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
    $insert->execute();

    $date -> modify('last day of next month'); // Changed to relative string & moved to end of loop
endfor;
```